# Mi método buscar me devuelve la primera posición siempre y no la que le pido

Tags: java

Saludos a todos amigos.
Tengo un inconveniente con mi código, mi método buscar me está devolviendo la primera posición solamente, cuando recorro todo el vector en busca de mi cadena, pero parece que no funciona. Este es mi método:

```
public String textoEnLista(List<String> le, String nombre) {
    String cadena = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       if (arrNum.contains(nombre)) {
           cadena=arrNum.get(i);
       }
    
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

La cadena a buscar se la paso a través de un textbox:

```
public String textoEnLista(List<String> le, String nombre) {
    this.arrNum = le;
    for (int i = 0; i < le.size(); i++) {
        if (le.contains(nombre)) {
            cadena=arrNum.get(i);
        }
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

No sé que más hacer, porque me devuelve el primer elemento de la lista y no el que pido, no sé que pueda estar sucediendo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mas que el primero, siempre te devuelve el ultimo... y en los dos casos, es la misma funcion con algun error?

Answer (score 1):

Es porque se está usando `contains()`. Eso causa que en la primera iteración `contains()` busque en todo el arreglo y si encuentra el elemento devuelve verdadero y por eso siempre toma el primero.

Para solucionar eso se puede usar `get()` que evaluará solo el elemento en la posición actual.

```
for (int i = 0; i < le.size(); i++) {
      if (le.get(i).equals(nombre)) {
            cadena = arrNum.get(i);
       }
    
}
```

---

También se puede simplificar el método de búsqueda así:

```
public String textoEnLista(List<String> le, String nombre) {
    
    // obtener el índice del elemento
    int index = le.indexOf(nombre);
    // si el índice es menor que cero ( no existe ) retornar
    // cadena vacía, de lo contrario retornar el elemento de búsqueda
    return index < 0 ? "" : nombre;
    
}
```

Comment: Wow! gracias! me funcionó perfecto, aunque tuve que hacerle unos ajustes porque no me estaba funcionando el list.elementAt así que usé un vector, lo llené con lo que habia en la lista y ya :D gracias!

Comment: Lo siento, mi error. En lugar de `elementAt()` es `get()`.